# Using a combination of fields in a WHERE clause

Tags: sql

I have two tables with similar key fields:

```
TABLE_A (KEY1, KEY2, KEY3, KEY4, A, B, C ...)
TABLE_B (KEY1, KEY2, KEY3, KEY4, A, B, C ...)
```

I want to delete records from TABLE_B where the set of keys are not present in TABLE_A.  So, something like:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_B 
WHERE (KEY1, KEY2, KEY3, KEY4) 
NOT IN ( SELECT KEY1, KEY2, KEY3, KEY4 FROM TABLE_A )
```

What is the best way to do this?  Would it be with some type of join?  I have a basic understanding of SQL, but it starts to get fuzzy when it comes to these types of functions.

Thanks!

Comment: "and this is clearly invalid sql" -- no, actually it is accepted in exactly the way you have written it by some databases. It would help if you could add information about what database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE b FROM TABLE_B b
LEFT JOIN TABLE_A a ON a.KEY1=b.KEY1 AND a.KEY2=b.KEY2...
WHERE a.SOMEID IS NULL
```

Comment: You're deleting the wrong records from the wrong table. The question asks for records from `TABLE_B` that do *not* exist in `TABLE_A`. You're deleting records from `TABLE_A` that *do* exist in `TABLE_B`.

Comment: No, don't think I am. The LEFT JOIN is selecting all rows and the where is filtering out the rows that don't exist in A.

Comment: @hvd - no, this is right. The `WHERE _ IS NULL` is called an exclusion join, and will do exactly what the OP needs.

Comment: @StefanMai You edited the answer so that it would be correct, which is fine, but I commented on the original answer.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn The original answer, which I commented on, had `DELETE a FROM ... INNER JOIN ...`

Comment: @hvd You're right, about 4 seconds after I posted it I edited it to say "ack, this wrong, editing", and then a few minutes later I posted the correct solution. Wasn't sure which one you were commenting on since your comment came after I posted the updated answer. My bad.

Comment: @StefanMai Also edited my comment to be a bit nicer, that was unnecessary. Sorry about that.

Comment: On this matter, I wish a) edit history for answers was stored. and b) comments could be "resolved by" answers. There are multitudes of cases where someone's comment improves the answer and then the comment is left orphaned. Sorry for the misunderstanding @hvd

Answer (score 2):

A sub-select will do the trick

```
DELETE FROM
   TABLE_B B
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM TABLE_A A
               WHERE
                    A.KEY1 = B.KEY1 AND
                    A.KEY2 = B.KEY2 AND
                    A.KEY3 = B.KEY3 AND
                    A.KEY4 = B.KEY4
               );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is valid standard SQL:1992 syntax and a good approach.

Of course, the syntax is not supported by all SQL products e.g. [mySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/row-subqueries.html) and [PostgreSQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/row-subqueries.html) support it, [SQL Server](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/299231) does not (click on those links for details).